# how to create batch file for diskpart cmd in windows which can lock (read only) and unlock the drive

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to create batch files to switch on/off read-only mode of drives.

I have created two batch files which call diskpart, and two text files that contain the commands to be passed to diskpart.

When I run the diskpart commands separately, they work; But when I run them through the batch file and text files, they don't work.

---

## Batch-file to lock disk

```
diskpart /s readonlyfile.txt > logfile .txt
pause
```

---

## Batch-file to unlock disk

```
diskpart /s offreadonlyfile.txt
pause
```

---

## `readonlyfile.txt` (for locking the disk)

```
diskpart 
list disk
select disk 1 
attributes disk set readonly
```

---

## `offreadonlyfile.txt` (for unlocking the disk)

```
diskpart 
list disk
select disk 1 
attributes disk clear readonly
```

---

Comment: I think you have some typos in your question regarding the names of the script files. In the batch files, both are called readonlyfile.txt whereas maybe the first should be lock.txt and the second unlock.txt.   If it is not a typo then that is the problem, if it is a typo then look at the error level returned.

Comment: There is a space between logfile and .txt, is this a typo? if not then use "log file .txt" otherwise it will be seen as two separate parameters.

Comment: If I recall correctly, `diskpart` requires admin rights.  If you have UAC enabled, you might need to have your batch script [prompt for elevation](https://sites.google.com/site/eneerge/home/BatchGotAdmin) before running `diskpart`.

Comment: Users usually operate with volumes identified by drive letters and shown in File Managers. It makes sense to create just one batch script without using any extra .txt files that would ask a user to enter a drive letter, show relevant disk status, and offer to lock or unlock the disk with all its volumes.

Answer (score 0):

You need administrative privileges to use diskpart, and if you don't have them, then your batch script will fail silently. To automatically request administrative privileges, you can use visual basic in conjunction with your batch script. You can also use simple redirect to auto-create the temporary files for you and delete them when your done

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
REM  --> Check for permissions
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"

REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
    echo Requesting administrative privileges...
    goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    exit /B

:gotAdmin
    if exist "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" ( del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" )
    pushd "%CD%"
    CD /D "%~dp0"
    set /p "mode=Do you ant to set read or write: "
    :: call the first 4 letters of the string
    call :%mode:~0,4%
    pause
endlocal
goto eof

:read
    echo.diskpart>readonlyfile.txt
    echo.list disk>>readonlyfile.txt
    echo.select disk 1>>readonlyfile.txt
    echo.attributes disk set readonly>>readonlyfile.txt
    diskpart /s readonlyfile.txt>logfile.txt
    del readonlyfile.txt
exit /b 0

:writ
    echo.diskpart>offreadonlyfile.txt
    echo.list disk>>offreadonlyfile.txt
    echo.select disk 1>>offreadonlyfile.txt
    echo.attributes disk clear readonly>>offreadonlyfile.txt
    diskpart /s offreadonlyfile.txt
    del offreadonlyfile.txt
exit /b 0
```

Source for the UAC prompt script: https://sites.google.com/site/eneerge/scripts/batchgotadmin